# How to stay awake after lunch?

Tags: personal-care, sleeping

In the afternoon after lunch, I often find myself nodding off.  How can I stay awake and focussed?  I don't drink coffee.

Comment: Go for a short walk.

Comment: Doing that already (20 minutes)